# How to count clicks of an anchor tag?

Tags: php

I have a anchor tag:

```
<a href="abc.php?a=1">Count Click</a>
```

I want to count number of times this link has been clicked.

In abc.php I use the following code but it is not working:

```
$b = $_GET['a'];
$b += 1;
echo "Number of Times Clicked=".$b;
```

Comment: store it in session variable

Comment: Possible of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972290/counting-clicks-on-anchor-tag)
**OR**
Go with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133012/auto-increment-when-clicked-an-anchor)

Comment: Dont store the click count on the url, anyone can mess with that in their browser

Comment: You can make it without php. Just parse access.log on your server.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Use a POST instead;

```
$a = intval($_POST['a']);

session_start();
$b = intval($_SESSION['clickCount']);
$b += $a;
$_SESSION['clickCount'] = $b;
session_write_close();
```

Comment: P.S. Make sure you do some empty validations before updating the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the value of this variable somewhere, because when you send GET request the page is refreshing and your value is missing.

You can store this value in session. See http://php.net/manual/features.sessions.php 
or cookies see http://php.net/manual/features.cookies.php or in some database on server.

And then get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all recommend you to store values in `$_SESSION` and also use `$_POST`

*Why use `$_SESSION` & `$_POST`?* because no one can mess up with your application.

**Basic Example (PHP):**

```
<?php
session_start();
$varCount = 0;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $var = intval($_POST['var']);
    $addVar = $var+1;
    $_SESSION['newVar'] = $addVar;
}
else{
    unset($_SESSION['newVar']);
}
if(isset($_SESSION['newVar'])){
    $varCount = intval($_SESSION['newVar']);
    echo $varCount;
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="var" value="<?=$varCount?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```